# HTML & CSS Pre-loader Enquiry

Tags: html, css

I saw that many sites have pre-loaders, and saw sites such as http://cssload.net which allow you to make them. But the question is, is it just HTML and CSS or are there scripts behind site pre-loaders that make the site wait until all of the data is loaded?

All advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually the loaders that you watch in those pages are just images or Css fnctionalities and doesn't have any script (dark side) behind just the ones that the page give you.
 about show or hide the preloader, basically you show the preload until your data is loaded after it, you can use a javascript method to hide the preloader (actually the div tag where is stored).